# ie problem with fading in text

Tags: internet-explorer, text, fade

Does anyone know how to fix the ie problem with fading in text? It looks jagged and the bg fix doesnt apply to me cause i have a gradient (havent tried it though to see if it does actually work). I have tried the remove filter but no luck so far. Any ideas?

Comment: what technique are you using to fade the text? please show us some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its an anti aliasing problem that IE has with opacity or the alpha filter i think. Possible fixes:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-prevent-jagged-text-in-ie

http://hurtsmybrains.wordpress.com/2010/01/21/jquery-fadein-fadeout-cleartype/

http://www.kevinleary.net/jquery-fadein-fadeout-problems-in-internet-explorer/

Comment: Ill take a look at the links. Thanks Ben. Can you tell me why ie doesnt fix those issues?? Im having a lot of problems with ie in generall.

Comment: Because its crap. Fact. http://www.joelanman.com/2009/12/ie-bug-fading-animation-makes-text-render-without-anti-aliasing/ This explains it

Comment: i took away the gradient and put a bg on the fading element. Its much better but i can still notice a little antialiasing. Thanks so much for  your time!:D

Comment: No worries, if the answer helped just remember to accept it :)