# Font Anti-Aliasing with jQuery fadeIn

Tags: jquery, css

Right now I have multiple fadeIn() and fadeOut() events happening when the mouse is hovered over different divs. The text in the fading in div looks really pixelated until after the fadeIn event is finished, then it kind of "pops" into a smoother looking text.

I am wonder if it is possible to tell the div to smooth the font prior to actually fading in or can I only achieve this affect by making the div an image?

Check out the venn diagram hover at http://www.daemondeveloper.com

Comment: I'm not seeing any "pixelation." http://jsfiddle.net/g2k8E/ .  What browser and screen resolution are you using?

Comment: Added a little pause: http://jsfiddle.net/g2k8E/1/ Safari/Mac seems to use a "cheaper", thinner looking anti-aliasing while animating.

Comment: maybe its because im using a 2D transform as well? check it out on my site http://www.daemondeveloper.com its the divs that fade in when you hover over the venn diagram

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This used to be a wider problem, but it's still an issue with IE. There are a few things you can do to work around this. First, make sure your fading element has a background.

The bigger problem is how IE renders text rendering through its opacity filters. Besides the obvious anti-aliasing, the letterforms shapes can actually change considerably too. A solution is to pre-apply IE's opacity filters to the element at 99%. This is essentially opaque, but it makes sure the element will render consistently during your jQuery effects.

Building on Ivan's jsfiddle, this one demonstrates the effect of backgrounds on fading text (tested in IE8): http://jsfiddle.net/joemaller/WLjXW/

The key is a css rule like this:

```
#sometext {
  background: #fff;
  -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=99)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=99);
}
```

Similar question:  [ie problem with fading in text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780430/ie-problem-with-fading-in-text)
More on IE opacity rules: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html